# Using gaussian smoothing for lat/long and value (xyz) data

Tags: r, spatial, arcgis, smoothing

I am trying perform Gaussian Smoothing of the z values that are associated with lat/long values. Each Lat/Long that I have is the centroid of a 1-mile by 1-mile grid. Here's an example of data:

```
latitude <- c(40.607674, 40.607048, 40.606419, 40.605785, 40.605152, 40.604515, 40.603874)
longitude <- c(-91.865349, -91.846184, -91.827026, -91.807861, -91.788704, -91.769547, -91.750381)
value <- 1:7
```

These lat/longs are in the WGS 1984 coordinate systems. One important thing to note is that I do not have access to rgdal library, however I do have access to ARCGIS (I don't have Spatial Analyst License, though) to project these values to another coordinate system.

So far I have been able to create a SpatialPointsDataFrame in R using these values. My intent was to convert the SpatialPointsDataFrame into a matrix representation for the Gaussian smoothing, but I haven't been able to do that successfully.